# Can't run second python file via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to run **send_mess.py** from my main application **main.py** so that the two applications run in parallel to each other.

```
def mailing_launch(self):
    global p
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'send_mess.py'])
    self.cancel_button.configure(state=customtkinter.NORMAL)
    self.start_button.configure(state=customtkinter.DISABLED)
```

This code worked fine, but when I moved the project to another computer, it refuses to run:

***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'***

If I use

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['send_mess.py'])
```

it I get an error:

***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'send_mess.py'***

All files are in the same shared project folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My system does not have `python`, so I assume that `python` is not always available. The sure thing to use instead if `sys.executable` which points to where the Python interpreter is, so replace that one line you have with:

```py
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'send_mess.py'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to the current interpreter with `sys.executable`. Also, if you are running the script from a different working directory, you might have to parse the path to your other script as well, I did this with `pathlib`, assuming both files are in the same folder

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

python_path = sys.executable
script_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("send_message.py")

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script_path])
print("do other stuff")
p.wait()
```